# Where are WhatsApp call logs stored?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, call-history

I know about the .db files and files that are used to store messages or so, but I need to know where are the call logs stored too. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

All user installed application data are stored in `/data/data/package_name` and database(.db files) are stored in `/data/data/package_name/databases`.
You need to manually find which db from `/data/data/package_name/databases` file is  call logs file.