# Does whatsapp store call logs in files?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I need to parse the call log, in order to get the timestamps and duration of each call with a particular contact. I'm on android. Is it feasible? I prefer using python but now the language doesn't matter, I just want to know if it's feasible.

Does whatsapp store calls in a log file on android I can parse?

What kind of database  is it and how to open them? a simple sqlite viewer? They seem to be ecrypted

Comment: It stores them [in a database](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/181523/131553). Linked answer does not specify which one but once you locate that you should be able to

Comment: @beeshyams What kind of database  is it and how to open them? a simple sqlite viewer?

Comment: I don't think it is an "end-user" problem therefore the question is not suitable for this site.

Comment: They are encrypted. See [this](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2770982)

Comment: I haven't tried it yet so can't give you help beyond this